# Accessing data from text box

Tags: javascript

```
function testTask06()
{
    var cipherText = document.getElementById('cipherTextBox').value;
    var indexCharacter = document.getElementById('indexCharacterTextBox').value;
    document.getElementById('plainTextBox').value = (decryptMessage(cipherText, indexCharacter, plainArray, cipherArray));
}
```

I want to get values from textbox called 'cipherTextBox' and 'indexCharacterTextBox', then use those values in my function decryptMessage and then display result in textbox 'plainTextBox'. It doesnt work but i'm wondering if it's because my function decryptMessage is wrong.

Comment: Yes, it looks like your function is wrong. Could you please post it instead?

Answer (score 2):

[This basic example](http://jsfiddle.net/Raynos/E6vMD/1/) works

```
function foo() {
    var cipherText = document.getElementById('cipherTextBox').value;
    var indexCharacter = document.getElementById('indexCharacterTextBox').value;
    document.getElementById('plainTextBox').value = 
        decryptMessage(cipherText, indexCharacter, [], []);
}

function decryptMessage(a, b) {
    // dummy function
    return a + b;
}

document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", foo, false);
```

There's probably something wrong with your `decryptMessage` function. We need to see that.